# Testing a route with a query string in PHPUnit/Laravel

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I am trying to test a route that will return a status code 500 if not visited with the correct query string parameter.

The route is http://localhost:8000/apiRequest?q=ASX.AX

I have done this

```
public function test_api_response()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->call('GET', '/apiRequest', ['_token' => Session::token()], $parameters = ["q" => "ASX.AX"]);

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());  
}
```

But the response is 500. Any help?

Comment: Find solution in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474554/laravel-phpunit-testing-get-with-parameters]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$parameters = ["q" => "ASX.AX"]` for `$parameters = ["q" => "AXS.AX"]`.