# Laravel phpunit testing get with parameters

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am writing some tests for my controllers but one of my tests doesn't work. It's supossed to search and **get the results back to the page**. But it's actually redirecting to the home page. Here is my code:

```
use DatabaseMigrations;
protected $user;
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->seed();

    $this->user = factory(User::class)->create(['role_id' => 3]);
}

/** @test */
public function test_manage_search_user()
{
    $response = $this->followingRedirects()->actingAs($this->user)->get('/manage/users/search', [
        'choices' => 'username',
        'search' => $this->user->username,
    ]);

    $response->assertViewIs('manage.users');
    $response->assertSuccessful();
    $response->assertSee($this->user->email);
}
```

The URL you should get to make it work look like this:

```
http://localhost/manage/users/search?choices=username&search=Test
```

I checked again and it looks like it's not given in the **parameters with the get request**. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.5 am I using I could do this: $response = $this->followingRedirects()->actingAs($this->user)->get('/manage/users/search?choices=username&search='.$this->user->username.''); but that isn't as neat as I want it

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had the same issue trying to test `GET` Requests, you actually can't pass parameter with the `$this->get('uri', [header])` but you can by using `$this->call`, if you check in *MakesHttpRequests.php* you can see that `this->get()` is actually using call method.

By adding an array to get method, you are changing the request headers, this is why you are not getting your parameters.

```
public function get($uri, array $headers = [])
{
    $server = $this->transformHeadersToServerVars($headers);

    return $this->call('GET', $uri, [], [], [], $server);
}

public function call($method, $uri, $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)
{
    $kernel = $this->app->make(HttpKernel::class);

    $files = array_merge($files, $this->extractFilesFromDataArray($parameters));

    $symfonyRequest = SymfonyRequest::create(
        $this->prepareUrlForRequest($uri), $method, $parameters,
        $cookies, $files, array_replace($this->serverVariables, $server), $content
    );

    $response = $kernel->handle(
        $request = Request::createFromBase($symfonyRequest)
    );

    if ($this->followRedirects) {
        $response = $this->followRedirects($response);
    }

    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

    return $this->createTestResponse($response);
}
```

So if you want to test a `GET` Request you will have to do this:

```
$request = $this->call('GET', '/myController', ["test"=>"test"]);
```

In your controller you should be able to get theses parameters like so:

```
public function myController(Request $request)
{
    $requestContent = $request->all();
    $parameter = $requestContent['test'];
}
```

Answer (score 23):

I'm using Laravel 5.X (more precisely 5.6), you can pass custom parameters using:

```
 $response = $this->json('GET',  '/url/endpoint',['params'=>'value']);
```

Comment: You really saved my day!

Comment: Also allow to add headers

Comment: That doesn't appear to work with Lumen 5.8.13 and \AlbertCht\Lumen\Testing\TestCase ‍♂️

Comment: Worked for me with Laravel 7.19.0

Comment: This now also seems broken on Laravel 5.6, but still works on Laravel 5.5. Effectively the controllers get a null as Request object during the ->json('DELETE', 'path', ['some'=>'array']) call.

Comment: It appears if you have a function signature like `destroy($id, Request $request = null)` that recent that Laravel 5.6 phpunit will just goes "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Okay I guess I don't really need to attach/inject the Request I prepared". I now removed the null expectation and swapped the position so Request is first, and everything seems to work now.

Comment: A 422 response is returned by Laravel when an Ajax request is made and has validation errors, when normally on validation error you would get 302.

Comment: This is a nice solution, as it retains any authentication, cookies, headers that you have have set up. The accepted answer does not do that.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the route helper to build a url with query string. in your case i would do something like this. Assuming the route name is manage.users.search

```
$route = route('manage.users.search', [
    'choices'=> 'username',
    'search' => $this->user->username,
]);

$response = $this->followingRedirects()
    ->actingAs($this->user)
    ->get($route);
```

Comment: Using the route() helper is neat

Answer (score 3):

In order to send parameters with GET requests.

1. If you use the `route()` method then you can pass the data as the second parameter.

   `$response = $this->get(route('route_name', ['key' => value]));`
2. If you using URL directly, you could use like this

   `$response = $this->get('url?' . Arr::query(['key' => value]));`

Do whatever you want to do with `$response`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the request helper to merge in http get parameters as such:

```
    /** @var \Illuminate\Http\Request $request */
    $request = request();
    $request->merge([
        'choices' => 'username',
        'search' => 'Test'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me simply pass the parameter as part of the url as follows:

```
$response = $this->get('api/endpoint?parameter1='.$this->dynamicParam);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a helper function:

```
if (!function_exists('extend_url_with_query_data')) {
    function extend_url_with_query_data(string $url, array $queryData): string
    {
        if ($queryData == []) {
            return $url;
        }

        $glue = mb_strpos($url, '?') === false ? '?' : '&';

        $queryString = http_build_query($queryData);

        return "{$url}{$glue}{$queryString}";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$queryData = [
    'works' => true,
];

$this->get(
    extend_url_with_query_data('/api/v1/example', $queryData)
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I would do it like this:

```
$this->actingAs($this->user);

$response = $this->get('/manage/users/search', [
    'choices' => 'username',
    'search' => $this->user->username,
]);

$response->assertViewIs('manage.users');
$response->assertSuccessful();
$response->assertSee($this->user->email);
```

Comment: My problem is that it doesn't give the parameters with it.
It only works when I do this:  $this->followingRedirects()->actingAs($this->user)->get('/ma‌​nage/users/search?ch‌​oices=username&searc‌​h='.$this->user->use‌​rname.''); which doens't look that neat

Comment: May i ask how are you retrieving parameters in the search method?

Comment: Currently I am able to get them with $request->get('choices')) for example

Comment: You simply need to perform assertions on what you are actually doing in that controller. Not that you receive the user email in the response.

Comment: This option is stupid if you check the parameters, this is changing headers & I don't agree on the point that this shouldn't be tested, this is a highly controversial topic about testing, and you are not making a good point here.