# Laravel PHPUnit unable to test GET parameters

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a Laravel 8 app that I'm working on where I need to use GET parameters (e.g. `test?num=1`) but unfortunately, I don't appear to be able to figure out how to run the unit tests against this.

I've followed the guidance I can find online (including [Laravel phpunit testing get with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474554/laravel-phpunit-testing-get-with-parameters), which looked very promising) however, none of the approaches seem to work.

To try and figure out the issue, I've created a VERY simple version and I'm getting the same behaviours. If I go to the URL directly it works as expected but the unit tests fail.

##### `routes\web.php`

```
Route::get('/test', 'TimeController@test')->name('myTest');
```

##### `app\Http\Controllers\TimeController.php`

```
public function test()
{
    return $_GET['num'] ?? "Num not provided";
}
```

##### `test\Unit\Http\Controllers\TimeControllerTest.php`

```
/** @test */
public function num_test_1()
{
    $params = ["num" => "1"];
    $response = $this->get('/test?num=1');
    $response->assertSeeText("1");
}
/** @test */
public function num_test_2()
{
    $params = ["num" => "1"];
    $response = $this->get('/test', $params);
    $response->assertSeeText("1");
}
/** @test */
public function num_test_3()
{
    $params = ["num" => "1"];
    $response = $this->call('GET', '/test', $params);
    $response->assertSeeText("1");
}
```

All three of the above tests fail with the message

> Failed asserting that 'Num not provided' contains "1".

I have even gone to the lengths of deleting the `node_modules` and `vendor` folders just in case I had a corrupt PHPUnit package or something.

Am I missing anything obvious? This feels like something that should be pretty easy to do and something that a lot of people will have done before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work fine.

You should change your method like this:

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    return $request->input('num') ?? "Num not provided";
}
```

Or with `query` method:

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    return $request->query('num') ?? "Num not provided";
}
```

You can also pass your desired default value if none found instead of using `??`:

```php
public function test(Request $request)
{
    return $request->input('num', 'Num not provided');
}

public function test(Request $request)
{
    return $request->query('num', 'Num not provided');
}
```